# Count and display how many times values changed in a column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

At the start sorry for my poor english, i will try my best to explain everything.
Is there a way to count how many times value in column D has been changed and show it in column E? 
In this example in column D person can select two values from list - "☐" and "☑". In column E i would want to see how many times person changed their selection. Lets say for for E3 i want to see how many time D3 was changed, for E4 to show how many times D4 was change and so on. 
Thank you for all help!

[image: example]

[Example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hcEWL1LNz3RVk_cjrLoS9QO0HfukYH6DCfqdoG33DpQ/edit?usp=sharing)

The only thing i found was somehitng like that:

```
function onEdit(e) {
   if(e.range.getA1Notation() == "D2") {
    var sCounter = e.source.getRange("E2");
    var counter = sCounter.getValue();

    if(counter === 0) {
      counter = 1;
    } else {
      counter ++;
    }
    sCounter.setValue(counter);  
  }  
}
```

The problem is that it only counts one cell and i need it to work for the whole column.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a sample of your code and we'll give you some help ;-)

Comment: I wrote the code as an answer, because i don't know how to use this website well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet()
  var editColumn=e.range.getColumn()
  var editRow = e.range.getRow()
    if(editColumn == 4 && editRow >=2) {
       var sCounter = s.getRange(editRow,editColumn+1,1,1);
       var counter = sCounter.getValue();
    if(counter === 0) {
      counter = 1;
    } else {
      counter ++;
    }
    sCounter.setValue(counter);  
  }}
```

Here is my test spreadsheet you can copy and try:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I5_NVMKPvqN9J2sSlcLRnQbzoVF4iRKOuXJ5mshb-RY/edit?usp=sharing